# How to manually update Snap package, Kolourpaint

Tags: updates, snap, kolourpaint

Currently the Snap-package `Kolourpaint` is broken, at least on my system (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS). And there do not seem to be any current updates.

```
$ snap refresh kolourpaint
snap "kolourpaint" has no updates available
```

Is it possible to do a manual update from the `apt-get` repository version of `Kolourpaint` somehow? I saw a tool called `snapcraft` that is supposed to update from .deb files - would that work, and if so, what would be the entire process?

(This question changed a lot as I researched Snaps. I hadn't used `Kolourpaint` in a few months, clicked it - and it was broken. Couldn't find how to update it in Snap, but found this to update the apt-get version: [Update KolourPaint](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2461531). That installed the CLI version, which works. I had *thought* that Snap was just a "pretty" front-end to the apt-get installer, so this had updated my `Kolourpaint` "package", but quickly found out that was wrong - Snap is an entirely different ecosystem.)

So now, I have a GUI-friendly paint-package that I can click on a PNG file, and have it run - except it doesn't. Or I can go to the CLI and run a *different* package - and have it work. It would be nice to reconcile this somehow.

Comment: To get an updated Colourpaint Snap, ping that Snap's author. If the Snap is broken, file a bug report with that Snap's author. If a Snap has been abandoned, report it on http://snapcraft.io, so the Snap will be reviewed and perhaps removed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will install the deb instead of the snap

```
sudo snap remove kolourpaint
sudo apt install kolourpaint
```

or GUI for discover (kubuntu)
search
Kolourpaint
then
uninstall it
next
click on sources ubuntu-...(a lot of text)
and then install it.
edit:
am i getting upvoteed because i told some one to uninstall a snap

Comment: Ah, I already *did* install the apt version of kolourpaint. I didn't specifically *remove* the snap-version, but unless you have reason to believe the second one will replace the first one, this won't work.

Comment: Remove the snap version

Comment: also run the kolourpaint command and tell me what it out puts.

Comment: Hm - removing the snap-kolourpaint "worked", in the sense that when I click on the GUI Icon (or right-click a PNG file and select Kolourpaint) - it runs the apt-get version. (which is version 19.12.3, the latest). So it solves my problem of not wanting to have to go to the CLI to run the program. But it's basically saying to not use the Snap version of the software, just use the apt-get version.

Comment: let me clear some stuff up the snap , deb (which you say is the apt-get version) , rpm ,flatpack, appimage ,aur and all other packaging methods have the same kolourpaint but each one is not aware of any other packaging methods so if you install two of the same package it will most likely brake.

Comment: and each one has it's owns avantiges and disadvantigts

Comment: Yes, I get that they are different package "ecosystems" (didn't realize that before starting this question, had thought snap was just a front-end to apt-get). But the snap-kolourpaint is *already* broken, which is the problem. I hadn't ever installed the apt-get-kolourpaint before this problem.